# Complex Numbers - Quartic

Tags: complex-numbers

Find two distinct real roots of the equation $z^4-3z^3+5z^2-z-10$, and hence solve this equation completely.

The problem is how do you find the two distinct real roots?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 0):

$$z^4-3z^3+5z^2-z-10=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(z-2)(z+1)((z-2)z+5)=0$$

So, we've got three equations:

- $$z-2=0\Longleftrightarrow z=2$$
- $$z+1=0\Longleftrightarrow z=-1$$
- $$(z-2)z+5=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z^2-2z+5=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z=\frac{-\left(-2\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(-2\right)^2-4\cdot(1)\cdot(5)}}{2\cdot1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4-20}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{-16}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z=\frac{2\pm i\sqrt{16}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$z=\frac{2\pm 4i}{2}$$

Comment: How have you reached : $$z^4−3z^3+5z^2−z−10=(z−2)(z+1)((z−2)z+5)$$

Comment: My question is how did you solve to get the following factors (z−2)(z+1)((z−2)z+5)=0

Comment: Can you explain your hint

Comment: This is less of a hint than it is an outright answer...